# making a shell 'source' file use relative paths

Tags: shell

I have the file: myvars

```
MONO_PREFIX=/opt/mono
export MONO_PATH=$MONO_PREFIX/lib/mono/2.0
```

I "use" it, by calling:

```
source myvars
```

I want to change `/opt/mono` to be relative to the location of the myvars file instead of being absolute. How could I do this?

Comment: that depends greatly on where the 'myvars' file is in relation to /opt where is it? also why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: myvar will be one directory higher than where I want MONO_PREFIX to point.  I want to do this because I want to have a monodistribution that can be placed in different places on the filesystem (not system installed), while still working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work in Bash:

```
MONO_PREFIX="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}/subdir"
```

This should work in ksh:

```
MONO_PREFIX="${.sh.file%/*}/subdir"
```

And this is for zsh:

```
MONO_PREFIX="${funcsourcetrace[1]%/*}/subdir"
```

These will point to a directory called "subdir" below the directory where the file being sourced resides.